# Do iTunes Connect sales chart show updates as well as new downloads?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Just curious, does the sales chart in iTunes Connect combine the stats from updates and new downloads?

Answer (score 1):

The downloadable iTunes Connect sales and trend reports separate new sales and update downloads by separate line items with a different code for each type.  You can also select separate charts for new downloads or for updates in the app and on the web site.